# Why I can't include some headers from C++17 on mac

Tags: c++, macos, c++17, header-files

**My system:** macOS Catalina(10.15.4)

> Brew config
>   Clang: 11.0 build 1103
>   Git: 2.21.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
>   Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
>   Java: 1.8.0_101
>   macOS: 10.15.4-x86_64
>   CLT: 11.4.1.0.1.1586360307
>   Xcode: N/A

**Issue:** can't include some C++17 headers: *execution*, *filesystem*
while can include the other like: *any*, *variant*.
Most of C++17 features like structured binding, template parameters deduction etc works.

**Example.** Trying to build a file with the following code snippet:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility> //std::pair
#include <tuple> // std::tie
#include <algorithm> // std::clamp

#include <optional> // std::optional

#include <map>
// ... other stuff

#include <execution>
namespace parallel_algoritmhs {
  void show() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& e) {e+=100;});
int main() {
//... use 
}
```

I am building with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all -o main c++17.cpp
```

Update:
I have tried suggested:

```
clang -std=c++17 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all -o main c++17.cpp
clang++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all -o main c++17.cpp
```

And getting the same result.

If I comment out code snippet related to different execution strategies, while leaving other code snippets like:

```
#include <any>
namespace any {
  void show() {
    std::any v = 42;
    v = 4.2;
    v = std::string{"hello"};
    std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(v) << '\n';
  }
}

namespace map_cpp17 {
  void show() {
    std::map<int, std::string> myMap{ { 1, "Gennady" }, { 2, "Petr" }, { 3, "Makoto" } };
    auto node = myMap.extract(2);
    node.key() = 42;
    myMap.insert(std::move(node));

    std::map<int, std::string> m1{ { 1, "aa" }, { 2, "bb" }, { 3, "cc" } };
    std::map<int, std::string> m2{ { 4, "dd" }, { 5, "ee" }, { 6, "ff" } };
    m1.merge(m2);

    std::map<int, std::string> m; m.emplace(1, "aaa"); m.emplace(2, "bbb"); m.emplace(3, "ccc");
    auto [it1, inserted1] = m.insert_or_assign(3, "ddd"); std::cout << inserted1; // 0
    auto [it2, inserted2] = m.insert_or_assign(4, "eee"); std::cout << inserted2; // 1
  }
}
```

Everything compiles

With

```
#include <execution>
```

getting:

```
fatal error: 'execution' file not found  
#include <execution>
```

I wonder what might be the problem behind that and how to fix this.
Thank you!

Update 2:
brew info llvm:

```
llvm: stable 10.0.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Next-gen compiler infrastructure
https://llvm.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/llvm.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, python@3.8 ✘
Required: libffi ✘
==> Requirements
Build: xcode ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
```

Update 3:
clang --version

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Does your compiler provide these headers? If not, then it's just an incomplete C++17 implementation.

Comment: You mentioned your clang version, but you're building with gcc...

Comment: On osx, try using clang instead of gcc.

Comment: @jtbandes Tried with "clang -std=c++17 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all -o main c++17.cpp" getting the same result

Comment: The standard library version matters too. Are you using libc++? https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html

Comment: @smac89 Tried, got the same result

Comment: It should be `clang++`, not `clang`

Comment: @jtbandes Found here: https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#c-17-specific-configuration-macros that "On macOS and FreeBSD libc++ is the default standard library and the -stdlib=libc++ is not required."

Comment: @smac89 I tried with g++, clang, clang++, getting same result, if I comment out snippet related to <execution> all other snippets compiles fine

Comment: I use `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ --version` to get to my C++ clang.

Comment: @Eljay I don't have /usr/local/opt/llvm in the system

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using the Clang you installed. The official LLVM Clang doesn't *have* a version 11.0! LLVM is only on version 10.0 (check `brew info llvm`). You're using Apple Clang, which comes with its own installation of libc++. Presumably to catch this exact type of problem, Apple Clang responds to `clang --version`/`clang++ --version` with the "future" version 11.0. However, Apple's distribution is actually a bit behind the state of the art, and it simply isn't updated to these features.

When you install LLVM with Homebrew, it doesn't automatically set it up the new `clang`/`clang++` to be easily callable, because things might expect `clang` to specifically mean "Apple Clang" and break if that changes. You should add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin` (which Homebrew symlinks into the LLVM installation) to your `PATH` (which is where your shell and other programs search for programs). In an already running shell session

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
```

will switch to using the newly installed LLVM Clang until you exit the session. Putting this line in a shell startup file, like `~/.bash_profile`, will set up this adjustment to be applied every time you open a new shell.

Alternatively, like @Eljay does, you could just manually type out the full path to the new `clang`/`clang++` (`/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang`/-`++`), thereby bypassing the search into `PATH`, but that's a pain. In any case, you'll know you got it right if `clang --version`/`clang++ --version` gives you `10.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added update 2, update 3 to my question with the output of brew and clang commands, from the brew output it looks like that there is only one clang binary in the system. And there is no "/usr/local/opt/llvm" on my system

Comment: @spin_eight • if there is no `/usr/local/opt/llvm` on your system, I suspect you have not `brew install llvm` yet.

Comment: @Eljay So did I understand it right: Apple Clang doesn't support whole set of C++17 features, so I should install official  LLVM Clang?

Comment: @spin_eight Yes. Sorry, I misread your question and assumed you had already installed LLVM. After you do so, you still have to follow my instructions to make the system use it over Apple's Clang.

Comment: @HTNW I have installed llvm, while doing: "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all -stdlib=libc++  -o main c++17.cpp" getting: error: no member named 'execution' in namespace 'std'

Comment: @spin_eight • You can use `__cpp_lib_execution` to check for implementation.  As per [feature test macro support](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/FeatureTestMacroTable.html), the `__cpp_lib_execution` functionality is not implemented yet in clang, but is implemented in [GCC 9.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017).